# Close div onclick <a> jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use this code to display a div onclick:

```
;(function($) {
    $(function () {
        $('.m-help .m-text').hide();
        $('.m-help')
            .live('click', function () {
                $(this).find('.m-text').show();
            })
            .live('click', function () {
                $(this).find('.m-link-close-button').hide();
            });
    });
    $(document).bind('m-ajax-after', function (e, selectors) {
        $('.m-help .m-text').hide();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

And with this HTML:

```
<div class="m-help">
    <div class="m-text" style="width: 40px;">
        <?php echo $_helpHtml ?>
        <a href="#" class="m-link-close-button"><span>x</span></a>
    </div>
    <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="details m-link"></a>
</div>
```

This does work onclick to display the div, but I want to use the X mark inside the div to close the div again.
Closing the div does not work.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: as a side note: as of jquery 1.7, 'live()' is deprecated, use 'on()' in stead (https://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: It's probably worth noting that [**Links are not Buttons**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event delegation

```
$('.m-help').on('click', function (event) {
    var close = $(event.target).closest('.m-link-close-button').length;
    $(this).find('.m-text')[close ? 'hide' : 'show']();
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/9e47j19L/1/**

Answer (score 0):

Use click event on a tag to close the div:

```
function($) {
    $(function () {
        $('.m-help .m-text').hide();
        $('.m-help')
            .live('click', function () {
                $(this).find('.m-text').show();
            });

            $(".m-link-close-button").live('click', function () {
               $(this).closest('.m-text').hide();
            });
    });
    $(document).bind('m-ajax-after', function (e, selectors) {
        $('.m-help .m-text').hide();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks! That does work, but it removes the <a> after closing the div. So it is not possible to reopen the div after closing it.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the parent of your close button with `parent()` so you can do it this way :

```
(function($){
   $('.m-help .m-text').hide();
   $('.m-help').live('click', function(ev) {
       $(this).find('.m-text').show();
   });
   $(".m-link-close-button").live('click', function (ev) {
           $(this).parent().hide();
   });
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: Tried that, but that does not close the div. It does display the div.

Comment: do you load your '.m-help' with ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
HTML

```
<div class="m-help">
<div class="m-text" style="width: 40px;">
    <?php echo $_helpHtml ?>
    <a href="#" class="m-link-close-button"><span>x</span></a>
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="details m-link">Click</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".m-text").hide();
   $(".m-link").click(function () {
   $(".m-text").show();
});
   $(".m-link-close-button span").click(function () {
   $(".m-text").hide();
});
```

Working fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/cncf5Lz9/

Comment: Tried your code, but that does not work. It does not close the div.